# SSL_set_tlsext_host_name API not found in libssl 1.0.2e or 1.0.2g

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-16.04

SSL_set_tlsext_host_name API not found in library libssl 1.0.2e/1.0.2g. However as per openssl changelog https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x43, SSL_set_tlsext_host_name should be available from 1.0.0 onwards.

I need SSL_set_tlsext_host_name API to set SNI.

OpenSSL package installed is

```
user@xy0:~$ sudo apt list -a openssl
Listing... Done
openssl/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15 amd64 [installed]
```

I tried to locate on ubunutu with libssl 1.0.2g install

```
readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0  | grep SSL_set_tlsext_host_name
```

no result. SSL_set_tlsext_host_name is not exported. Am i missing something?

Comment: Do you have openssl-dev installed? For Ubuntu it may be `libssl-dev` package.

Comment: Yes, its 1.0.2g version.

Comment: You won't find it by grepping the output of readelf. Its a C macro not a function.

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK from the doc and the code i have written on top of these API. SSL_CTRL_SET_TLSEXT_HOSTNAME is micro and SSL_set_tlsext_host_name() function to invoke.

Comment: Thanks @MattCaswell. I looked at the source again, should be looking at SSL_ctrl which invoked within SSL_set_tlsext_host_name micro.

Comment: @VishwajeetDusane How did you solve the problem at the end ?